# Python Combine two list

Tags: python

I have

```
A = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J']
B= ['a','b','c']
```

I want to combine the list that 'a' is combine with first three element of list A , 'b' with the next three and 'c' with the last three as shown below

```
C = ['Aa','Ba','Ca','Db','Eb','Fb','Gc','Hc','Jc,]
```

how can I go about it in python

Comment: What code have you written so far? Please add it to your question.

Comment: You can do it by grouping `A` into chunks of 3 elelements. Then use nested loops that combine them.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This isn't a cartesian product

Comment: Am I right in saying this question has again been incorrectly marked as duplicate?

Comment: @Jacob: You are right. My mistake. I misread the requested output: `C = [...`. It looks similar, you must admit. (Also +1 since I can't think of a suitable `itertools` solution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a list comprehension you could do this. Although I suspect there's a nicer way to do it.

```
[f"{capital}{B[i//3]}" for i,capital in enumerate(A)]
```

`i` will increment by 1 for each letter in `A` so we can do floor division by 3 to only increment it every 3 iterations of `A` giving us the correct index of `B` and just use an f-string to concaninate the strings although `capital + B[i//3]` works too.

Comment: Bonus points to explain the solution for the Op?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I'm trying to think of a more understandable/readable way to do it but if I can't think of one I'll give it a go :)

Comment: I think what you have is great but it is cryptic to some.

Comment: You can also apply some [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) magic which should be significantly faster *(and quite more universal)*: `list(starmap(concat, zip(A, cycle(B))))`. Imports: [`cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), [`concat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.concat).

Comment: A very ugly `itertools` solution could be: `C = [a+b for a,b in zip(A, chain(*[list(repeat(z,3)) for z in B]))]`

Comment: @quamrana, `chain.from_iterable()`?